# Almost elementary equivalence

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, asymptotics

Let $ M_1 $ and $ M_2 $ be stuctures over a language $ L $.

Let $ forms_n(L) $ be the set of all first-order formulas over $ L $ with length at most $ n $ (let assume we use a reasonable definition of length).

Define the *common formulas* of $ M_1 $ and $ M_2 $ denoted by $ comm(M_1,M_2,L) $ to be the set of all formulas $\phi $ such that $ M_1 \models \phi $ and $ M_2 \models \phi $.

In addition, the *common rate* of $ M_1 $ and $ M_2 $ denoted by $ cr_n(M_1,M_2,L) $ is the value $ \Pr_{\phi \in forms_n(L)} (comm(M_1,M_2,L) ) $.

We say that two structures are *almost elementary equivalent*, if their common rate coverages to $ 1 $.

Is there a study on such definitions?

Specifically, are there two (finite) groups which are almost elementary equivalent but not elementray equivalent?

What if we demand another properties of the common-rate (for example, $ cr_n(M_1,M_2,L) = \frac{2}{3} +O(\frac{1}{n})$?

I believe it too hard to cope with those definition practicaly, and that it almost impossible to find the common rate of arbitary non elementary equivalent structures.

Another question arised from the comments is how much the probability value sensitive to the syntax setting.

Comment: It seems to me that your probability value could be sensitive to how one sets up the syntax.

Comment: In other respects, your question has an affinity with 0-1 laws in finite model theory. For example, see http://www.jstor.org/stable/2695069?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents. But you have two fixed, possibly infinite models, and so it isn't the same thing.

Comment: You right. It doesn't really matter the syntax choosen (this decisens are arbitrary), and the question is interesting for all standard definitions.

Comment: That may be true.  But if the definition is sensitive to syntactical issues that are usually considered irrelevant, then it could also be taken as an indication that one doesn't have the right notion yet. You are trying to place a measure on degrees of elementary equivalent, which is a very interesting idea, and so it is worth pursuing.

Comment: You right. I believe it's no so sensitive (from asymptotics perspective), but it interesting to check it out

Comment: Here is an idea for an example: let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be the same, with infinitely many constants, except that the interpretation of one of those constants differs between $M_1$ and $M_2$. So they will not be elementarily equivalent, but intuitively, most assertions will not be about that one constant, and so in the limit we might hope for almost elementary equivalence. (Problem: I think it may be false that most assertions do not mention the constant.)

Comment: Is $ L $ a language with only a finitly many constants (with equal symbols)? To be more expressed, in that case, maybe we can choose $ M_1, M_2 $ over $ \{ 0,1 \} $ such that in $ M_1 $ every $ c_i $ interpreted to be $ 0 $, but in $ M_2 $ every $ c_i $ interpreted to $ 0 $ except $ c_1 $ which interpreted to be 1. 

It seems difficult to analyse it because we get that $ forms_n (L) $ are infinite (maybe we can, in general, divide the question between finite language and infinite language).

Comment: In addition, I think that it's not so clear to define a probability measure when $forms_n(L) $ are infinite sets.

Comment: But we can ask a related interesing question: Let $ L $ be the language with only $ m $ constant-symbols (and equal relation), and let $ M_1, M_2 $ be the structures over $ \{ 0, 1 \} $ when $ c_i^{M_1} := 0 $ and $ c_j^{M_2} := 0 $ for $ j \neq 1 $ and $ c_1^{M_2} := 1 $. So what is the common-rate of $ M_1 $ and $ M_2$?

Comment: The first example is just what I had in mind. To get the formulas finite, we should dribble in the constants little-by-little. Thus, "size n" should involve only constants up to $n$ and variable symbols $x_i$ for $i<n$. (It is the same issue for you with variable symbols.) That way, the probability is still well-defined.

Comment: The common-rate will be $1-1/e^2$, or about 86.5%, I believe, not $1$, since I believe that will be the proportion of formulas not mentioning $c_0$.

Comment: It still interesting. Maybe it a upper bound for the rate of non elementary equivalence structures (but the cojeture is too far right now, and probably false).

Comment: So we have two definitions of rates: one for finite languages and one for infinite languages (the definition for infinite languages apply to finite languages).

Comment: Even in a finite language, if you have variable symbols $x_i$ that count as just one symbol, then there will be infinitely many formulas of size less than $n$, unless you somehow change the syntax, or go by Goedel codes or something. This kind of thing is what I meant by the concept depending on syntax.

Comment: Now I got it. Maybe we can take a logically equivalent classes of formulas instead of formulas.

Comment: No. It doesn't change that problem. We can make additional equlivance for the formulas which consider a case that the formulas are the same modulo the variables.

Comment: But I see now that it's more complicated.

Comment: Here's a tractable example to pursue:  Consider groups in the language with a ternary relation Rxyz for xy=z, and no other symbols.  The sentence "forall x forall y Rxxy -> Rxyx" is false in Z4 but true in Z2xZ2.  What fraction of the n-quantifier sentences agree on the two groups?